# How to do validation in JQuery dialog box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to put validation in my dialog box. One will be empty validation and second will be email validation.

```
if (emailAndPasswordCheck) {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 160,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        modal: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Please Give more Info.

Comment: show us what you have tried... :-)

Comment: This is going to need a lot more information.

Comment: Your downvotes will increase unless you show your hardwork and attempt  done to solve the issue. So post some code to get immediate help

Comment: hey guys dont decrease my points

Comment: @user3196995 Don't worry.....points won't go in minus... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, your email validation nad empty validation code is as for PHP file
Also download jquery from some link with mentioned version - jquery-1.9.1.js. Created one abc,js abc.js

```
          <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript/jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript/newempcontact.js"></script>
        <span id="validate_msg"></span>
        <label id="lbl_frstname">* First Name :</label>
        <input class="hover" type="text" id="txt_firstname"  minlength="1"  maxlength="26" placeholder="First Name"/>
        <span class="sfirstname"></span>


        <label id="lbl_pemail">* Personal Email :</label>
        <input class="hover"  type="text" id="txt_pemail"  placeholder="Personal Email"/>
        <span class="spemail"></span>
```

You can place is any where..
 create one more php file with any name say abc.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){
    echo "This is not valid email id!";
}else{
    echo "This is valid email id!";
};
}

?>
```

And your abc.js file is as: -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#slct_pstate, #slct_tstate' ).bind('change click scroll ',function(e) {
    fill_cities();
});
$('#slct_tstate').bind('change click scroll ',function(e) {
    fill_cities();
});

email_validation()
```

//replace form_nempcontact with your form name--

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
        submit_fxn(); 
        $('#form_nempcontact').submit(function(e) {
            return false;
        });
});


}); 

function email_validation(){
   $('#txt_pemail').focusin(function(e) {

if($('#txt_pemail').val() == ''){

    $('span.spemail').text('Go for valid email address').addClass('validatectrl');;

}
else{
    emailvalidattion($('#txt_pemail').val());
}
 }).blur(function(e) {
   $('span.spemail').html('');
 }).keyup(function(e) {
    emailvalidattion($('#txt_pemail').val());

}); 
};//****

  function emailvalidattion(email){
    $.post('PHP/check.php', {email:email}, function(result){
    $('span.spemail').text(result).addClass('validatectrl');
});
 };//**


 function submit_fxn(){

    var check_flag = 0;
            var fname = $('#txt_firstname');
            var fname_val = fname.val();
            var fname_dftlngth = fname.attr('minlength');
            var fname_usrdftlngth = fname_val.length;

     if(fname_usrdftlngth == 0 || fname_usrdftlngth < fname_dftlngth){
        $(fname).css({
        "background-color":"#FF0000",
        "border":"soild 2px yellow"

        });

        check_flag = 1;


    }else{
        $(fname).css({
        "background-color":"#FFFFFF"


        }); 


    }
    if(check_flag == 1){            
        $("#form_nempcontact").submit(function() {
                $("#validate_msg").text('');


        });
    }
            if(check_flag == 0){

            //---Write your code here

              }
    };
```

//your CSS code as -

```
      p.validate_msg {
          border: 1px solid #FF0000;
          font-weight: bold;
           padding: 10px;
      display:none;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    color:#FFFF00;

  }
      span.validatectrl, p.validatectrl  {

    color:#FFFF00;
   font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-size:14px;
  padding-left:8px;
}

       span.validatectrlgreen  {
color:#090;
padding-left:8px;
font-style:italic;
     }
```

If this answer is correct, please mark it as an answer

Comment: Who used this code for checking....

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) is generally well-regarded and easy to use.