# Call javascript function on submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to call JavaScript function while submitting the form.

Here is code but while submitting function not called, please suggest something and I want to show error messages using javascript method as well , how can I show error messages in validation using JavaScript.

```
<form id="register" name="register"  onsubmit="validateForm()">
<label for="Username"> Username </label><br>
<input type="text" class="register-control" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"> <br><br>
<label for="Password"> Password </label><br>
<input type="password" class="register-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br><br>
<label for="Confirm-Password"> Confirm Password </label><br>
<input type="password" class="register-control" id="Confirm-Password" name="Confirm-Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ><br><br>

<label for="email"> Email </label><br>
<input type="email" class="register-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"><br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            "Username": {
                required: true,
            },
            "Password": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "Confirm-Password": {
                required: true,
            },
            "email": {
                required: true,
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is JavaScript code

```
function validateForm()
{
    var password = document.forms["register"]["Password"].value;
    var con-password = document.forms["register"]["Confirm-Password"].value;
    if(password != con-password)
    {
        document.getElementById('password-error').style.visibility='visible';
        alert("not matched");
    }
    alert("matched");
}
```

Comment: onsubmit="validateForm()" replace with onsubmit="return validateForm()". try this

Comment: @kruti i already tried not working.

Comment: can anybody please share working code like on jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to a syntax error in your script. When you see errors like that, look into the JavaScript console of your browser.

In this case, `con-password` is not a valid variable name. What JavaScript sees is:

```
var con - password ...
```

i.e. the code says "substract `password` from `con`". Try an underscore instead:

```
var con_password ...
```

Comment: thanks learan a new thing ,added but still fuction didn't work.

Comment: event returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: -1 for not also showing the OP that his `validateForm()` function is completely superfluous, and that the jQuery Validate plugin has a `submitHandler` built into it.

Answer (score 5):

Do not need to do anything extra for password matching, just add  `equalTo: "#Password"` to it as shown in the below example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            "Username": {
                required: true,
            },
            "Password": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "Confirm-Password": {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#Password"
            },
            "email": {
                required: true,
            }
        },
       messages: {
         Password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
         Confirm-Password: {
                    required: "Please provide a confirm password",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
            // Your function call  
            return false; // return true will submit form
            }
    });
});
```

Working example:

```
<form id="register" name="register" action="" method="post">
<label for="Username"> Username </label><br>
<input type="text" class="register-control" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"> <br><br>
<label for="Password"> Password </label><br>
<input type="password" class="register-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br><br>
<label for="Confirm-Password"> Confirm Password </label><br>
<input type="password" class="register-control" id="Confirm_Password" name="Confirm_Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ><br><br>

<label for="email"> Email </label><br>
<input type="email" class="register-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"><br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            "Username": {
                required: true,
            },
            "Password": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "Confirm_Password": {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#Password"
            },
            "email": {
                required: true,
            }
        },
       messages: {
         Password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
         Confirm_Password: {
                    required: "Please provide a confirm password",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
            // Your function call  
            return false; // return true will submit form
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it works for me, but i want to use javascript as well .

Comment: as far as I know jQuery is JS ;)

Comment: You can use  submitHandler: function(form) { /*your function call*/ return false;  }

Comment: @Anubhav above trick work for me but it showing error messages in both condition when passwords are different and same .

Comment: Not possible, you are doing something wrong. see the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/. Note change hyphen(-) to underscore(_) in the names of input field!

Comment: +1 for posting the correct answer and I agree, the OP's code could be so much better if he'd simply leverage the features of the plugin.  However, it ***is*** possible to show messages upon success with the jQuery Validate plugin... one only needs to read the documentation and look at the [code on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+is%3Aanswer+success).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe instead of checking if passwords matches you can add new rule in validation?
something like:

```
           ... "Password": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        "Confirm-Password": {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#Password"} ....
```

and for messages add:

```
... messages: {
           "Password": "Your message",

        }...
```

and all in all something like this: `

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("Your form name").validate({
    rules: {
        "Username": {
            required: true,
        },
        "Password": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        "Confirm-Password": {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#Password"
        },
        "email": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
        messages: {
            "Password": "Your message",
            "email": "Your Message",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});`
```

Comment: thanks can you please write messages part for Password and Email just for confirming the syntax.

Comment: added some. But could there my some spelling mistakes. Don't have possibility at this moment to check this.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i add onclick event on the submit button to call the function `validateForm()`

html

```
<form id="register" name="register">
<label for ="Username"> Username </label><br>
<input type="text" class="register-control" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"> <br><br>
<label for ="Password"> Password </label><br>
<input type="password" class="register-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" ><br><br>
<label for ="Confirm-Password"> Confirm Password </label><br>
<input type="password" class="register-control" id="Confirm-Password" name="Confirm-Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ><br><br>

<label for="email" > Email </label><br>
<input type ="email" class="register-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"><br><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

this is the `validateForm()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var username = $('#Username'),
            password = $('#Password'),
            confirm  = $('#Confirm-Password'),
            email    = $('#email');

        $('#register').submit(function(ev){
            // check if all fields is not empty
            if(username.val() === '' || password.val() === '' || confirm.val() === '' || email.val() === '') {
                ev.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
                alert('All fields are required.'); //alert message
                //check if password and confirm password is equal
            } else if(password.val() != confirm.val()){
                ev.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
                alert('password did not match.'); //alert message
            } else {
                return true; // submit form if validation has passed.
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you missed - you need to use method="post" in

http://jsfiddle.net/dLbLS/

```
    <form id="register" name="register"  method="post" onsubmit="validateForm();" >
    <label for ="Username"> Username </label><br>
  <input type="text" class="register-control" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"> <br><br>
  <label for ="Password"> Password </label><br>
 <input type="password" class="register-control" id="Password" name="Password"  placeholder="Enter Password" ><br><br>
  <label for ="Confirm-Password"> Confirm Password </label><br>
  <input type="password" class="register-control" id="Confirm-Password" name="Confirm-Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ><br><br>

  <label for="email" > Email </label><br>
  <input type ="email" class="register-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"><br><br>
 <button type="submit" >Submit</button>

 </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

```
    <input type="button" id="close" value="Submit" onClick="window.location = 'validateForm()'">
```

do one thing i am sending one link please go through that link i have commented my code over there copy and paste it and test it....

[How to do validation in JQuery dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254210/how-to-do-validation-in-jquery-dialog-box/21254784#21254784)

if this answer is correct then please mark it as answer for others....