# Dynamic Form validation for multiple records

Tags: jquery

I have here a form validation. I need to create a Dynamic Form validation for multiple edit records.
How to make this in for loop?

Here's my script

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;

    $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {

    var validation_holder = 0;

        var project         = $("form#register_form input[id='n_app_cn']").val();
        var project_regex   = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check    

        var counter         = $("form#register_form input[id='n_counter']").val();
        var counter_regex   = /^[0-9]+$/; // reg ex qty check

        /* validation start */  

        if(project == "") {
            $("span.val_project").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!project_regex.test(project)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_project").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_project").html("");
            }
        }

        if(counter == "") {
            $("span.val_counter").html("");
        } else {
            if(!counter_regex.test(counter)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_counter").html("Refresh to avoid Database Error!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_counter").html("");
            }
        }

        if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End
</script>
```

I saw this script but how I can mix it up with my current script? Help please

```
function validate() {
for(i = 0; i < document.form.rowcount.value; i++){
if (document.getElementById("client_id" + i).value=="") {
alert("empty");
document.getElementById("client_id" + i).focus();
return false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: At a time only one form will run. And our JQuery is the faster then server script...So, for every form you can use JQuery .. ..  And if you need any validation code for any control, I can give it you... Please reply me for this....

Comment: @Partap Yes only one form run with this code. Yes I need this.

Comment: @Partap Please teach me

Comment: I am nothing to teach you.... but i can share my code with you

Comment: @Partap Ok Please share it please

Comment: So, the mentioned link is working for you or not

Comment: @Partap I'm not that good in js or jquery. So I'm having hard time in your codes.

Comment: OKay, No issue, I will modify the code according your code..........
Please provide your full code, what is project and what is counter how  would i know

Comment: @Partap this is my code http://jsfiddle.net/pF4un/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) like,

```
function validate() {
    var flag=true;
    $("form#register_form input[type='text']").each(function(i){
        if (!this.value) {
           alert("empty");
           this.focus();
           flag=false;
           return false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

Call it `onclick` of `submit button` like,

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var validation_holder;
    $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function () {        
        var emptyFlag=validate();
        if(emptyFlag){
            // your remaining code for validation   
        }
    }); // click end 
}); // jQuery End
```

**Updated,** You can add `class` `required, project, counter` to check these fields and in your `js` change it like,

```
function validate() {
    var flag=true;
    $("form#register_form input.required").each(function(i){// use required class
        // same as above for all required fields
    });
    return flag;
}
```

And for `project class` test it like,

```
$('.project').each(function(){ // use $.each for all project class
    project = this.value;
    if (project == "") {
        // use $(this).next to show error in front of text box
        $(this).next("span.val_project")
               .html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else {
        if (!project_regex.test(project)) { // if invalid phone
            $(this).next("span.val_project").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            $(this).next("span.val_project").html("");
        }
    }
});
// Similarily you can add checks for item, counter, etc.
```

Comment: Like that, how to mix it in my current script?

Comment: @surname see my answer once again

Comment: can you make a fiddle for me? I'm having trouble with jquery :/

Comment: First you have to `set up your html and code` on `fiddle`, then I'll make it on work.

Comment: this in my current codes. This work for only 1 record. But when I used in php code and edit two or more records it works for the first record. I just need to work this code for multiple rows. http://jsfiddle.net/pF4un/

Comment: @surname add `classes` for all `mandatory fields` like, `required,project, item, etc.`. See my `updated answer`.

Comment: sorry for this but I'm having trouble in function validate. If it inside of jQuery(function($) { ?

Comment: No one is free to edit code for you...I have already my code to you please modify it accordingly.... and if you think my answer is correct then please hit it as an asnwer

Comment: If you can't then you can go to [validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: @RohanKumar It works, but when I tried to add this script in other input it's not working -_- it only works for project

Comment: @RohanKumar It works. Can I ask again? I have another script and that script is not working bcoz of changes.

Answer (score 0):

its very easy stuff just put your function on call of jQuery call like this.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;

    $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {
//Put start up test thats it.
for(i = 0; i < document.form.rowcount.value; i++){
if (document.getElementById("client_id" + i).value=="") {
alert("empty");
document.getElementById("client_id" + i).focus();
return false;
}
}
    var validation_holder = 0;

        var project         = $("form#register_form input[id='n_app_cn']").val();
        var project_regex   = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check    

        var counter         = $("form#register_form input[id='n_counter']").val();
        var counter_regex   = /^[0-9]+$/; // reg ex qty check

        /* validation start */  

        if(project == "") {
            $("span.val_project").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!project_regex.test(project)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_project").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_project").html("");
            }
        }

        if(counter == "") {
            $("span.val_counter").html("");
        } else {
            if(!counter_regex.test(counter)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_counter").html("Refresh to avoid Database Error!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_counter").html("");
            }
        }

        if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End
</script>
```

Comment: not like that. What I mean is add the for loop in my if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted the similar kind of code on another post.. Please modify the code accordingly and the link is as -

[How to do validation in JQuery dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254210/how-to-do-validation-in-jquery-dialog-box/21254784#21254784)

If this answer is right then please mark it as an answer so that others can use it as an reference in future