# How to validate username using jQuery Validation plugin when it must not be any combination of firstname and lastname

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to validate username using jquery validation when it must not be any combination of firstname and lastname.

for example Jon Doe using "jdoe" or "joed" or "jdo", etc.

Thanks Sparky
i am trying to do so but not got sucess, need help
var fn=$("#fname").val()
var lname=$("#lname").val()

var res=$("#username").val().search("j")
$("#output").val(res)

Comment: As you told - make all combinations you want to avoid and check the value. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: The jQuery Validation plugin is not the jQuery Validation Engine.  Please be more careful with tagging your question accurately.

Comment: yes but how to check this combination

Comment: Put some effort into writing your question and maybe somebody will put some effort into an answer.  See: http://sscce.org for tips.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer of your query is here. Please check it on the following link -

[How to do validation in JQuery dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254210/how-to-do-validation-in-jquery-dialog-box/21254784#21254784)

If this answer is ok for you then please hit it as an answer.....